MySQL Workbench no conecta Flask
estoy tratando de inicializar mi base de datos con Flask y me arroja el siguiente error... He exportado cada uno de los parámetros para poder iniciar mi base de datos con 'flask init-db' pero me da ese error...
$ flask init-db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\.venv\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 1105, in main
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\.venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\.venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\.venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\.venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\.venv\Lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 33, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 386, in decorator
    return ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\.venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\Python sin Fronteras\Proyecto_flask\todoer\todo\db.py", line 33, in init_db_command       
    init_db()
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\Python sin Fronteras\Proyecto_flask\todoer\todo\db.py", line 25, in init_db
    db, c = get_db()
            ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\Python sin Fronteras\Proyecto_flask\todoer\todo\db.py", line 10, in get_db
    g.db = mysql.connector.connect(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\.venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\.venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\.venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "c:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\.venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 208, in _open_connection     
    self._do_auth(self._user, self._password,
  File "c:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\.venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 137, in _do_auth
    packet = self._protocol.make_auth(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\.venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\protocol.py", line 99, in make_auth
    packet += self._auth_response(client_flags, username, password,
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\.venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\protocol.py", line 58, in _auth_response
    auth = get_auth_plugin(auth_plugin)(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\César Díaz\OneDrive\Escritorio\CURSOS\CURSOS\.venv\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\authentication.py", line 190, in get_auth_plugin  
    raise errors.NotSupportedError(
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported
(venv)

Estos son mis archivos...
init.py
import os

from flask import Flask, request, url_for, redirect, abort, render_template

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='mikey',
        DATABASE_HOST=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_HOST'),
        DATABASE_PASSWORD=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        DATABASE_USER=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_USER'),
        DATABASE=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE'),
    )

    from . import db
    
    # Inicializar la aplicación con los comandos personalizados
    db.init_app(app)
    
    @app.route('/hola')
    def hola():
        return 'Hello Moto'
    return app

db.py
import mysql.connector

import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext
from .schema import instructions

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=current_app.config['DATABASE_HOST'],
            user=current_app.config['DATABASE_USER'],
            password=current_app.config['DATABASE_PASSWORD'],
            database=current_app.config['DATABASE']
        )
        g.c = g.db.cursor(dictionary=True)
    return g.db, g.c

def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

def init_db():
    db, c = get_db()
    for i in instructions:
        c.execute(i)
    db.commit()

@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    init_db()
    click.echo('Base de datos inicializada')

def init_app(app):
    if app is not None:
        app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
        app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)

Y schema.py
instructions = [
    'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;',
    'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS todo;',
    'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;',
    'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;',
    """
        CREATE TABLE user (
            id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
            username VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
            password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
        );
    """,
    """
        CREATE TABLE todo (
            id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
            created_by INT NOT NULL,
            created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            description TEXT NOT NULL,
            completed BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY (created_by) REFERENCES user (id)
        );
    """
]

Mi lista pip en mi (venv)
$ pip list
Package                Version

alembic                1.13.1
blinker                1.7.0
click                  8.1.7
colorama               0.4.6
Flask                  3.0.3
Flask-Migrate          4.0.7
Flask-SQLAlchemy       3.1.1
greenlet               3.0.3
itsdangerous           2.2.0
Jinja2                 3.1.3
Mako                   1.3.3
MarkupSafe             2.1.5
mysql-connector        2.2.9
mysql-connector-python 8.3.0
pip                    24.0
SQLAlchemy             2.0.29
typing_extensions      4.11.0
Werkzeug               3.0.2
(venv)

mysql-workbench es una ide para conectar con una db, usualmente mysql.. quiero creer que tu problema viene por ahi, no?? despues, yo no tanto de python, pero ahi el error dice que no acepta algo.. alguna libreria mal instalada?

Si instalaste el conector de Mysql via pip install mysql-connector, desinstalalo e instala el paquete correcto: pip install mysql-connector-python. Más información. En la "package list" que pones veo que están ambos, elimina el connector 2.2.9.

Muchísimas gracias @aeportugal eliminé los 2 y reinstalé el mysql-connector-python... Solucionado!!!
